# Python. Очистка txt от дубликатов

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, парсер

С помощью комьюнити получилось спарсить txt файл в вид:

```
текст1
текст2
текст1
текст3
текст1
и тд
```

Теперь хочу очистить список от дубликатов. Пока пришел к такому:

```
with open('test.txt') as find:
    for line in find:
        m = list(set(find))
        print( m )
```

Дубликаты удаляются, но вывод получается корявый:

```
['текст3\n', 'текст2\n', 'текст1\n']
```

Как сделать чтоб и дубликаты удалить и список выводился нормально?

```
текст3
текст2
текст1
```

Comment: Отличный вывод. Не могут же переносы строк магическим образом пропасть :). Напечатать список можно так: `print(*m, sep='', end='')`

Comment: В вашем коде цикл for line in find совсем не нужен, потому что они ничего не делает.

Comment: print(*m, sep='', end='') - то что мне было нужно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать разделение на строки через `splitlines`:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    items = list(set(f.read().splitlines()))
    print(items)
```